# How to speed up search in dash?

Tags: unity-dash, search

I use Ubuntu 14.04. Search in dash is taking very long time. Is there any procedure to make the search faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the [Privacy Indicator applet](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/indicator-privacy/) and just turn off all the features you don't need.

Then (in the same applet) click on <kbd>Clear Zeitgeist log</kbd>.

That's the easiest and fastest way to improve the speed of the dash *while keeping the functionality you do need*.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some things to do:

1. Disable online search results:

   Launch <kbd>System Settings</kbd> and go to <kbd>Security & Privacy</kbd>, under the <kbd>Search</kbd> tab, turn off the check box which says `When searching in the Dash: include online search results`
2. Stop recording file and app usage:

   In <kbd>System Settings</kbd> and go to <kbd>Security & Privacy</kbd>, under the Files & Applications tab, first click clear records and then turn off `Record file and application usage`
3. Remove unwanted Unity lens, scopes:

   Open the Ubuntu Software Center and search for `unity-scope`. In the results, check the information on installed scopes and remove the scopes you don’t need...

Comment: This is absolutely correct, but also limits the functionality if you turn off application usage as well!  **:(**