# Ubuntu "incognito" mode?

Tags: permissions, cinnamon

I have a multi-user system running Ubuntu 14.04 with the Cinnamon desktop environment.

I found recently that recent file history is stored and accessible from the Applications Menu. This of course means that recent file history is stored in Linux, no matter what environment you're using.

There are times when I need to modify certain system/application files that don't contain root permissions, being in hidden folders, and I don't want them to get pampered with by other users using the system.

Is there either:

- A way to run Ubuntu in incognito mode?

**Or**:

- remove the option to store recent file history?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to speed up search in dash?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/645826/how-to-speed-up-search-in-dash)

Comment: @Fabby oh that is a duplicate? XD

Comment: Yup!  ;-)  And an even better answer!  You can selectively turn Zeitgeist off!  **>:-)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn off the recording of file history in ubuntu.
Open **System Settings** and select **Security & Privacy**.
Simply switch **OFF** "Record file and application usage".
From this tab you are able to **clear usage data** as well.

[image]